# Android studio Kotlin - tag utils

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to create a class that provide a class tag everywhere in my kotlin project. I don't want to use any library. A simple class/snippet could be fine to my personal project.
I want to use it to prevente everytime to create a String value TAG = "ClassName" and than use it in a log like:
Log.d(TAG,"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, maybe if someone needs it it might be useful. I found an elegant solution in KOTLIN:
[Here Snippet from my repo](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1984379).
And here my solution:

```
val Any.TAG: String
   get() {
    return if (!javaClass.isAnonymousClass) {
        val name = javaClass.simpleName
        // first 23 chars
        if (name.length <= 23) name else name.substring(0, 23)
    } else {
        val name = javaClass.name
        // last 23 chars
        if (name.length <= 23) name else name.substring(name.length - 23, name.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will break if you use Proguard or R8 (which is a large part of why most apps define a `TAG` string)

Comment: do you know better case?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'd need some sort of code-generation based solution.  I'm not aware of any.